# BQ: distribute amount over rows in array + plugin to match

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to distribute an aggregated amount over the rows of an array. Here what I started with:

```
WITH a AS (
  SELECT 1 AS key, 8.55 AS tot_tax
    , ARRAY(
        SELECT AS STRUCT 'item1' AS descr, 9.6 AS amt 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT AS STRUCT 'item2', 183.5
        UNION ALL
        SELECT AS STRUCT 'item3', 26.5
        ) items
  )

--query:

 SELECT * EXCEPT(items) 
  , ARRAY(
      SELECT AS STRUCT *
        , ROUND(amt/(SELECT SUM(amt) FROM UNNEST(items)) * tot_tax, 2) AS tax
      FROM UNNEST(items)
      ) items
 FROM a
```

However `SUM(tax)` <> `tot_tax` because of roundings (required). Hence I want to plug the small difference into the largest tax amount to make it match. 
I can do this in another query like so:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(items)
 , ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(tax)
      , IF(o = 0, ROUND(tax + (SELECT tot_tax - SUM(tax) FROM UNNEST(items)), 2), tax) AS tax
    FROM UNNEST(items) WITH OFFSET o
   ) items
FROM 
  (SELECT * EXCEPT(items) 
    , ARRAY(
       SELECT AS STRUCT *
         , ROUND(amt/(select SUM(amt) FROM UNNEST(items)) * tot_tax, 2) AS tax
       FROM UNNEST(items) ORDER BY amt DESC
      ) items
   FROM a)
```

Works well but it's cumbersome. 
Could this be done better (clarity + performance) in one single query or using a UDF (js/SQL) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(tax, pos),
      IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY amt DESC) = 1, 
        ROUND(tax + tot_tax - SUM(tax) OVER(), 2), tax
      ) AS tax
    FROM (
      SELECT * EXCEPT(ratio), ROUND(amt * ratio, 2) AS tax
      FROM UNNEST(items) WITH OFFSET AS pos, 
        (SELECT tot_tax / SUM(amt) AS ratio FROM UNNEST(items))
    )
    ORDER BY pos
  ) AS items)
FROM a
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - result is

```
Row key tot_tax items.descr items.amt   items.tax    
1   1   8.55    item1       9.6         0.37     
                item2       183.5       7.15     
                item3       26.5        1.03
```

Below is further streamlined/refactored version (might be less friendly readable though)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT  * EXCEPT(ratio, pos), 
      ROUND(ROUND(amt * ratio, 2) + 
        IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY amt DESC) = 1, tot_tax - SUM(ROUND(amt * ratio, 2)) OVER(), 0) 
      , 2) AS tax
    FROM UNNEST(items) WITH OFFSET AS pos, 
      (SELECT tot_tax / SUM(amt) AS ratio FROM UNNEST(items))
  ORDER BY pos) AS items)
FROM a
```

with exact same output

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I liked the window function over the unnested array - keep forgetting. Removed the `order by pos` to speed up as recordset is very large